# Pandas : Cumulative sum with moving window (following and preceding rows)

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have the following dataset :

```
date     sales
201201   5
201202   5
201203   5
201204   5
201205   5
201206   5
201207   5
201208   5
201209   5
201210   5
201211   5
201212   5
201301   100
201302   100
```

And I want to compute the cumulative sum of sales, from **the beginning** to the **actual date + 12 months**

So here :

```
date     sales   expected
201201   5       60
201202   5       160
201203   5       260
201204   5       260 
201205   5       260
201206   5       260
201207   5       260
201208   5       260
201209   5       260
201210   5       260
201211   5       260
201212   5       260
201301   100     260
201302   100     260
```

According to this question [How to compute cumulative sum of previous N rows in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787059/how-to-compute-cumulative-sum-of-previous-n-rows-in-pandas) I tried :

```
df['sales'].rolling(window=12).sum()
```

However I am looking for something more like this :

```
df['sales'].rolling(window=['unlimited preceding, 11 following']).sum()
```

Comment: Sorry, to ask this - why second value is 160 and third value becomes 260? What's the logic behind it?

Comment: First expected value is sum(sales from beginning until 201301) = 60.
Second expected value is sum(sales from beginning until 201302) = 160 as sales are 100 in 201301.
Then third value is 260 because I add the 100 sales from 201302, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cumsum` directly thanks `shift` by `11`, than use `ffill` to fill `NaN`s with previous value:

```
df['expected'] = df['sales'].cumsum().shift(-11).ffill()
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
      date  sales  expected
0   201201      5      60.0
1   201202      5     160.0
2   201203      5     260.0
3   201204      5     260.0
4   201205      5     260.0
5   201206      5     260.0
6   201207      5     260.0
7   201208      5     260.0
8   201209      5     260.0
9   201210      5     260.0
10  201211      5     260.0
11  201212      5     260.0
12  201301    100     260.0
13  201302    100     260.0
```