# Pandas: Sum Previous N Rows by Group

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sum the prior N periods of data for each group. I have seen how to do each individually (sum by group, or [sum prior N periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787059/how-to-compute-cumulative-sum-of-previous-n-rows-in-pandas)), but can't figure out a clean way to do both together.

I'm currently doing the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

sample_data = {'user': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],\
                'clicks': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)
df['clicks.1'] = df.groupby(['user'])['clicks'].shift(1)
df['clicks.2'] = df.groupby(['user'])['clicks'].shift(2)
df['clicks.3'] = df.groupby(['user'])['clicks'].shift(3)
df['total_clicks_prior3'] = df[['clicks.1','clicks.2', 'clicks.3']].sum(axis=1)
```

I don't want the 3 intermediate lagged columns, I just want the sum of those, so my desired output is:

```py
>>> df[['clicks','user','total_clicks_prior3']]
   clicks user  total_clicks_prior3
0       0    a                  NaN
1       1    a                  0.0
2       2    a                  1.0
3       3    a                  3.0
4       4    a                  6.0
5       5    b                  NaN
6       6    b                  5.0
7       7    b                 11.0
8       8    b                 18.0
9       9    b                 21.0
```

Note: I could obviously drop the 3 columns after creating them, but given that I will be creating multiple columns of different numbers of lagged periods, I feel like there has to be an easier way.

Comment: In your example, you don't seem to take into account the current row, but instead use the previous 3, which means the last row is ignored completely in results. Is this intended?

Comment: Yes, that is intended. In the real world I suppose I actually may not have the value for the current observation - good catch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is `groupby` + `rolling` + `shift`

```
df.groupby('user')['clicks'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum().groupby(level=0).shift()
```

```
user
a     0     NaN
      1     0.0
      2     1.0
      3     3.0
      4     6.0
b     5     NaN
      6     5.0
      7    11.0
      8    18.0
      9    21.0
Name: clicks, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a solution that works for each group, you can use `apply` to use it on the `groupby` object. For instance, you linked to a question that has `df['A'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=11).sum()` as an answer. If that does what you want on the subgroups, you can do

```
df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x: x['clicks'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=11).sum())
```